# What is coming up for scala in 2.10?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Obviously there is the **reflection** library but what else can we expect to see in the next release of scala? Any language changes? Is there a website where I can see a roadmap?

Comment: There is some more discussion here: [Scala Roadmap Post 2.9.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966068/scala-roadmap-post-2-9-0)

Comment: You could watch or read the notes of the [ScalaDays 2012 keynote](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/t0lyl/scaladays_2012_oderskys_keynote_where_scala_is/)
 by Odersky.

Comment: @daniel-c-sobral has prepared the following excellent guide to new Scala 2.10 features: http://www.slideshare.net/dcsobral/scala-210-english

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Martin Odersky announced new features at Devoxx several days ago. I blogged about it (you can also find photos and presentation slides [here](http://www.parleys.com/play/514892280364bc17fc56c0d3/chapter0/about).

Answer (score 23):

The smaller items:

- [Huge @deprecation cleanup](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/64)
- [`scala.Dynamic`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Dynamic) could be finally enabled by default
- [Huge](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/76) [improvements](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/77) [to](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/74) [documentation](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/58)
- [Many](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/63) [fixes](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/69) [which](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/85) make ScalaDoc a pleasure to use
- Fixes to the continuation compiler plugin
- [Faster hashing algorithm](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/fdba3583acc3387cda689d7cc56a8f4460fa1d27) for `Product`s and collections

Some changes which I hope will be included:

- Removal of `scala.dbc`
- [Removal of useless code examples and flower pictures](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/71) which currently ship with the standard library

Comment: Your main link to significant improvements/changes is broken.  It seems the hosting service provider is out of business.

Answer (score 16):

Martin Odersky just put slides from ScalaDays 2011 on the web.
Last few pages of the presentation shows the desired direction for Scala.

[Martin Odersky ScalaDays 2011 - Presentation Slides](http://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/01.%20Martin%20Odersky.pdf)

Comment: This is not a detailed road-map: shame, I would have hoped that they would have something more solid by now

Answer (score 1):

Odersky's talk [What's new in Scala 2.10](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8484) at [Java One 2012](http://www.oracle.com/javaone/index.html) contained pretty much the latest details about this.